# Visual Studio Project Properties: changing target framework version

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks

I can develop many things inside Visual Studio 2010.
But unfortunately **my clients can't even install .NET Framework 3.5** on their pc/laptop.
They **can only install .NET Framework 4.0 and above.**

My project was originally built using .NET Framework 3.5. Now I need to change the target framework version but I can't find an option to do this:

[image: image-1]

How can I make my project work with .NET Framework 4.0 or greater?

Comment: The .NET Framework is backwards compatible anyways. So you can run the 3.5 application on frameworks 3.5 and above. You can't run a 4.5 application on framework 4.0 and so on though. Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: but what i found is that, this client is unable to run my app that was developed under .net 3.5 that's strange for sure! @Jens, the appeared warning i got is 0xc0000007b

Comment: Ok, let's just hope it works after changing your application to 4.0. But there might be something wrong with the client's installation.

Comment: I guess so. It's very strange that his computer is unable to accept any .net 3.5 framework installation at all (web / offline) installation. I wonder. huhu,....

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Go to Compile Then Advance Compile Options...

Comment: Change the Target CPU to ANY so that i will be compatible to all type of CPU when deploying it.